# Solr: How to Search by Time *AND* Distance

Tags: scala, indexing, solr

We are working on an app using Solr to search by distance. A Solr consultant wrote the original code but is no longer available, so I, a Solr newbie, try to take this over. The current index insertion code looks like this:

```
{add: 
    {doc: 
        {id: <my_id>, 
         category: <my_type>, 
         resourcename: <private_flag>,
         store: <my_latlng>,
        },
     overwrite: true,
     commitWithin: <commit_time>
     }   
 }
```

And the query below properly returns all the documents near (mylat, mylng):

```
localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&q=category:"<mytype>"&fl=id&fq=
    {!bbox}&sfield=store&pt=<mylat>,<mylng>&d=<my_distance>&rows=200
```

All was well in paradise.  Now we need to add a time dimension, meaning instead of just retrieve nearby docs, we need to retrieve nearby docs within a specific time range (e.g. 2 days ago, 2 month ago).  This means adding to each index a "origin_time" field, and then modify the query to search for TIME plus distance.

Can anyone suggest how I should add this time field to the index and how to adjust the query to search by distance and time?

Thanks!

Comment: show your indexing code, usually when you add new docs in Solr it doesn't mean that old indexes are discarded

Comment: The code to add to the index is in the first code block above, is that what you mean?

Comment: OK, I replaced the scala code with the solr index code.  I hope that's what you mean

Comment: why you couldn't use SolrJ?

Comment: @mysterion - not sure why not, I inherited this code.  although it seems to work OK w/o SolrJ.  I need some advice on adding the ability to search by time as well as by locations.